# How to create a library exposing named configured singletons generated at runtime with Dagger 2?

Tags: dagger-2

I'm considering migrating to Dagger 2 some libraries. This library expose a configurable client, each configuration can be named and later retrieved in a singleton fashion.

Let me show a pseudo-code of how the library works from the user perspective:

```
// initialization
ClientSDK clientA = new ClientSDK.Builder()
       .configuration().attributes().here()
       .apiKey("someString") // set api key / credentials
       .build();
LibraryAuthenticationManager customAuthManager = new MyCustomAuthenticationManager();
ClientSDK clientB = new ClientSDK.Builder()
       .configuration().attributes().here()
       .apiKey("someStringElse")
       .customAuthManager(customAuthManager) // override some default
       .baseApiUrl("https://custom.domain.com/and/path") // override some default setting
       .build();
ClientSDK.setSingleton("clientA", clientA);
ClientSDK.setSingleton("clientB", clientB);
```

And when I need an instance elsewhere:

```
// usage everywhere else
ClientSDK clientB = ClientSDK.singleton("clientB");
clientB.userManager(); // "singleton" using the configuration of clientB
clientB.subscriptionsManager(); // "singleton" using the configuration of clientB
clientB.currentCachedUser(); // for clientB
clientB.doSomething(); // action on this instance of the ClientSDK
```

`ClientSDK` instances are created by the user of the library and the ClientSDK statically keep a map of singletons associated to the name.

*(The actual behavior of the SDK is slightly different: the naming is automatic and based on a mandatory configuration parameter.)*

It's like I have lot of singleton classes with a single point of entry (the ClientSDK) but since I can have multiple configuration of the ClientSDK each with his own singletons instances this are not really singletons.

If I would try write a library like that with Dagger 2 I would do something like:

```
class ClientSDK {

    @Inject SDKConfiguration configuration;
    @Inject LibraryAuthenticationManager authManager;

    ...
}
```

The problem is that I need each instance of the ClientSDK to have its own configuration and authManager (and many other services) injected. And they need to be definable (the configuration) and overridable (the actual implementation) from the library user.

Can I do something like this with Dagger 2? How?

I've seen I can create custom Scopes but they are defined at compile time and the library user should be the one defining them.

(the library is an Android Library, but this shouldn't be relevant)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be creating stateful/configurable Module instances and then generating separate Components or Subcomponents for each ClientSDK you build.

```
public class ClientSDK {
  @Inject SDKConfiguration configuration;
  @Inject LibraryAuthenticationManager authManager;
  // ...

  public static class Builder {
    // ...

    public ClientSDK build() {
      return DaggerClientSDKComponent.builder()
          .configurationModule(new ConfigurationModule(
              apiKey, customAuthManager, baseApiUrl)
          .build()
          .getClientSdk();
    }
  }
}
```

...where your ConfigurationModule is a `@Module` you write that takes all of those configuration parameters and makes them accessible through properly-qualified `@Provides` methods, your ClientSDKComponent is a `@Component` you define that refers to the ConfigurationModule (among others) and defines a [`@Component.Builder`](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.Builder.html) inner interface. The Builder is important because you're telling Dagger it can no longer use its modules statically, or through instances it creates itself: You have to call a constructor or otherwise procure an instance, which the Component can then consume to provide instances.

Dagger won't get into the business of saving your named singletons, but it doesn't need to: you can save them yourself in a static Map, or save the ClientSDKComponent instance as an entry point. For that matter, if you're comfortable letting go of some of the control of ClientSDK, you could even make ClientSDK itself the Component; however, I'd advise against it, because you'll have less control of the static methods you want, and will lose the opportunity to write arbitrary methods or throw exceptions as needed.

You don't have to worry yourself about scopes, unless you want to: Dagger 2 tracks scope lifetime via component instance lifetime, so scopes are very easy to add for clarity but are not strictly necessary if you're comfortable with "unscoped" objects. If you have an object graph of true singleton objects, you can also store that component as a conventional (static final field) singleton and generate your ClientSDKComponent as a [subcomponent](http://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html) of that longer-lived component. If it's important to your build dependency graph, you can also phrase it the other way, and have your ClientSDKComponent as a standalone component that depends on another `@Component`.

Comment: this looks like the right direction. I've started a new project and can't look into it right now, but I'll get back to it and try (and then accept answer or comment)